# Where are JAR Library for Google Maps Distance Matrix API?

Tags: google-maps, netbeans, maps, distance

I'm developing a Java server application with NetBeans, and I need to use Google Maps Distance Matrix API. I read Google and Github information and I saw a few YouTube videos, but I'cant find JAR files at [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/) and I'cant add libraries to my NetBeans'project...please, may you help me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I answered your question.  If you agree, would you mind marking my answer as the chosen solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Distance Matrix API is exposed via the Maven artifact identified as "`google-maps-services-java`" or Gradle artifact identified as: "`com.google.maps:google-maps-services`".  To use this, setup a simple Maven project and include thisdependency as described in the [README.md](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/#maven) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>(insert latest version)</version>
</dependency>
```

To use it, as described in the README, you'll need a Google API key and you'll need to plug in the latest versino ([currently 0.1.7](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/releases), but 0.1.8-SNAPSHOT is in development).

Alternatively, you can just download the Jar from Maven Central:

- [Browse](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.maps%7Cgoogle-maps-services%7C0.1.7%7Cjar)
- [Download](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/maps/google-maps-services/0.1.7/google-maps-services-0.1.7.jar).